# How to restrict access to local actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm searching for encapsulation methods like `private` for class members. I'd like an actor to provide accept some common harmless messages and privileged that could possible mutate state in undesirable way. I can also build proxy actor that would filter messages based on access policy. But both actors would be still available via full path actor ref. How can I made some actor ref private, that can be accessed only by its parent?

Answer (score 3):

Any actor can be addressed by any other actor so long as the path is known by using `ActorSelection`.

If you want to restrict certain messages, you can do so with things like package-private.

Say you have `DangerousActor` and you only want actors defined in the same package to be able to send `DangerousMessage`, but you also have `SafeMessage` and you're fine with anyone else in the actor system sending that.

```
package dangerous

object DangerousActor {
  private[dangerous] case object DangerousMessage
  case object SafeMessage
}

case DangerousActor extends Actor {
  import DangerousActor._

  def receive = {
    case DangerousMessage =>
    case SafeMessage => 
  }
}
```

Only actors also defined in the `dangerous` package will be able to reference `DangerousMessage`.